# Where SHOULD I ask about licensing?

Tags: discussion, scope

In a recent question (about running VMs on my desktop) I received a comment that licensing issues are outside the scope of this site and "we're not lawyers".

Fair enough, if that's the rule that's the rule. *But* licensing is a very important part of software and VMs are obviously very widely used these days, so where *can* I ask about such things in the SE universe?

Comment: Thanks @DavidPostill. It seems the matter is not as clear-cut as I thought, I don't believe my question "needs a lawyer" - just someone who understands about Windows licensing. Which I'd rather hope a sysadmin _would_!

Comment: Not everything has a site (yet!). The problem with licencing in many cases is that its a moving target, in constant flux and is terribly complex.  The best bet is to find someone who is doing it *now* and asking them, or actually reading the licencing terms and trying to understand now. Licencing is in no way part of our core hardware and software work

Comment: There is a difference between asking if something is legal an of something violates a license.  One requires a lawyer, in many places, a non-lawyer giving legal advice itself is illegal.  Anyone with an understanding of the license and the written language can ask if something in their opioion violated a license.  Link to the specific comment if you don't mind

Comment: The best place to ask about licensing is at the company doing the licensing.  They are the experts.

Comment: @fixer1234 that seems rather to fly in the face of the whole SE ethos. The best place to ask about an API is the person who wrote it, etc. Understanding licensing of the OS and software you use is surely a key part of a sysadmin's job, especially in the modern world of virtualisation (I'm not a sysadmin but surely)?

Comment: If you need to ask somewhere, going directly to the source will give you the most accurate and reliable answer.  Answers here about licensing are sometimes mixed because different users have different understandings, and may not know all of the nuances even if their understanding is basically correct.  Terms sometimes change with subsequent versions.  There are some users who can provide a complete and accurate answer, but how can you be sure those are the ones who answered, and where are you if you get multiple answers that are inconsistent, or one answer?

Comment: @fixer1234 a license question is easy to answer quote the relevant part of the license :-)

Comment: @Ramhound: I've had questions about Microsoft licenses where the license wording isn't clear.  Like what's the definition of a single machine?  Beyond the hardware components (is it the mother board or CPU?), suppose you dual boot.  If you install office on each OS, how many installations does that count as? (turns out to be one, which you wouldn't know from the license wording.)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the question, it can be on topic at Programmers or Law.SE - see [this discussion](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69/software-licensing-questions-from-stackoverflow) on Meta.Law.SE that I started.